# trigger node js file

Tags: php, node.js, command

I have a JS file that runs via node.js, so normally I crank open a terminal window and type something like `node myfile.js` and it runs and runs all day; fun.

Then when I want to reboot it, I hit control-c and and it quits. Then I can run the command again.

Now what I would like to do is be able to do this through a web page so that my users can run specific JS files and also be able to "reboot" them.

So two questions about this:

1. Is it possible, and if so how do I get started?
2. Is it safe, and if not, can it be made safe?

Based on swatkins response

i tried this and got nothing

```
 $output = exec("node -v");
 echo $output;
```

then i tried on my local machine and it worked fine what gives ?

also I'm still not sure about the security and the ability to stop a running script

Comment: No, `$output` should be passed as the second parameter of the exec function:  `exec("node -v", $output); print_r($output);`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you're on Unix-based OS:

You can run shell commands via the exec() function:

```
// in php file
// to start the script 
exec("node myscript.js &", $output);
```

`$output` becomes an array of each line of output, so you can see what the process id is. Then you would use that process id to kill the script:

```
exec("kill " . $processid);
```

Comment: and how would I then stop that script ? and is this safe to run ? also how do i know if its running ?

Comment: updated my answer - you'll need to get the process id, so by running `myscript.js` in the background (by appending `&` to the command), you'll receive a process id in the output array. You'll probably need to do some string manipulation to get the actual id, but then you just use that to kill the process.

Comment: this certain runs the script but doesn't give me any uoutput until i kill the process and then it gives me data that is written to console.log()

Comment: Not working for me. PHP can't find node. Is there a way to find path to node in php?

Comment: in windows $output returns the js file output not the PID and the php never end until the process is killed manually

Comment: @Aramil -- "Assuming you're on a Unix-based OS:" - I don't develop on windows, so can't help there.

Comment: @swatkins Its ok bro i found a workaround for windows in case someone need it http://stackoverflow.com/a/43851784/3201616

Comment: @smohadjer using the same (or similar) exec idea to run shell commands: `which node` is the shell that will give you the full binary path

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid any direct interaction with the shell. It would probably be the safest, to solve it this way:

- implement some overall "service"-script, that launches the user-node-app and keeps it running (something like https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor)
- Make it, so it automatically reboots on changes of either the relevant files or a database-entry
- With the user triggering a reboot, add a flag (timestamp?) to the database-entry or file that is watched by the reboot-script. It then will reboot the node.js-app/script.

Comment: Why wouldn't you have shell interaction? What's wrong with the accepted answer?