# Mix Node.js and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Could be possible to generate a page with PHP and then run Node.js to apply some edits to it?

On Google I've found [examples](http://webandphp.com/IntegratingNode.jswithPHP) of PHP and Node.js integration but they are always two different files which work together with Ajax or similar things.

My goal instead is to run Node.js (or something which can run javascript) in this way:

```
$html = "<html>
            <body>PHP
                <script>document.body.innerHTML = \"Javascript\";</script>
            </body>
         </html>";

$html = run_js($html);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Please explain why would you do that?

Comment: Technically, yes, but I would not advise it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I get a page from a remote server and I've an about 2k rows of JS which parses and edit it, and I'd like to move the action to server side without rewrite the entire script.

Comment: And how is PHP supposed to talk to node if not via AJAX? It's the same as thinking PHP speaks to MySQL over invisible wire instead of TCP/IP and network. You can have that `run_js` function, but it **will** involve some kind of HTTP request from PHP to node.

Comment: Afraid to say that that is just how it works. You could create a node preprocessor that runs as the main renderer and compile PHP scripts within that via CLI commands but otherwise you have to duplicate. If you are not worried about SEO stuff, then simply load in the node output into a DOM element after/while the page is loaded.

Comment: Having said all that... another way is to get the node output from a CLI command in PHP.... let me get back to you on that...

Comment: Yeah, here's your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8620731/892955

Comment: may be you can use node.js with php for running long process in multi thread environment  but don't mix both

Comment: Technically, this isn't such bad of a question but it lacks a lot of context. There are many people who try to put PHP and JS together for some reason, and had this question been asked right from the start - you might get some proper answers. However for your purposes - do you even need PHP in this case? Node does everything PHP can, why mix both if you can use only Node to achieve all of it?

Comment: @N.B. I need to use CURL to read headers of the remote page, then I need to get the content of the remote page and then run the JS. I don't know if Node.js can perform all these tasks.

Comment: Of course it can, JS uses XmlHttpRequest object to handle requests in the same fashion as PHP uses CURL. That means you can send and parse headers and content via JS. Therefore, Node can do it, question is only if you are sufficiently proficient with JavaScript.

Comment: I know jQuery but with Javascript I've not much experience.

Comment: You can use jQuery with Node, it runs all JS libraries as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Do not do this. It may be possible, but it's a really bad idea. Pick a single technology stack for your project and stick to it.

Splitting you project over multiple technology stacks does nothing of any value (whatever you're wanting Node to do could be done in PHP, and vice-versa), so all it really does is add a massive amount of complexity without achieving anything.

If you're going to even think about adding this kind of complexity to your system, you need to understand the implications: This will kill your performance; it will create a maintenance and debugging nightmare; it will probably introduce weird, hard-to-find bugs.

In short, I really, *really* advise you not to do this.

If you want to use Node.js, that's fine; use it. But don't mix it into a PHP system; start a new project from scratch.

Comment: My question is just to avoid to rewrite an already existing JS script, I know would be better use a single language.

Comment: I've seen the comments you've posted above, and thank you for clarifying what you're doing; the question does make a bit more sense now. :)  However, my angle would be that my paragraph about the implications still holds true. You're introducing a performance bottleneck and a long-term maintenance headache for the sake of a short-term saving of time and effort. And frankly, I'm not even sure it would save you that much time, given that you've got to set up a Node server and get it communicating with your PHP code.

Comment: I add that I've used phpQuery to rewrite the entire Javascript script in PHP.

Comment: @Spudley, I am thinking about a use case where mixing both technologies can be of value. e.g. in an ecommerce application, to read product catalogue from database, node is faster, while php is better for backend as developmentis faster in this.

Comment: @RameshPareek: I still disagree. The advantages of splitting the two platforms are outweighed by the disadvantages of having to maintain two platforms. There are use cases where I would consider doing it (and have done so), but probably not for what you've described except in extreme cases.

Comment: I had to do this once because I worked an a huge PHP codebase and needed a very specific function from a library that only existed in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you really really have to do this you can use PHP V8js. The built-in javascript engine that PHP comes with. [PHP V8js](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php). I agree however with the other answer that this should be avoided as much as possible.