# How to make a PHP and JS backend?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, server

I know that you can use PHP or node.js server-side, but is it possible to use both PHP and JS together, for example PHP calling a JS function?

My goal is to call JS for the more intensive math functions, but I don't want these to be seen on the clientside. I've tried searching many different sites but it seems my question is pretty specific. Thanks

Comment: Please read over https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , and its very helpful to attempt https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Randall: What would an MCVE of this question even look like? The question is quite clear, if a bit broad: Is it possible to call JS **server-side** from PHP and, if so, how?

Comment: I was about to answer this by recommending PHP V8js if you really want to do this.

Comment: Related but not a dupetarget: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760984/mix-node-js-and-php (that question is specifically about generating a "page" in PHP then passing it through JavaScript code to amend the page; this question isn't limited in that way).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess I misunderstood the point of stack overflow, being where we help with code attempted. Not broad questions sending people off to external websites or sources. My bad.

Comment: Whats wrong with js templating languages??

Comment: Agree, the question is pretty simple, just rather open-ended (lots of correct ways of doing so)

Comment: @Randall: Many -- most -- questions are code-specific. Not all by any means.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation because you can't use google cloud platform's free tier while running node. You can use google drive scrip files for your javascript and then call them via api. I'll be giving this a try in the next bit. If you need your scripts to be private though you'd have to use google's oAuth 2 which is far from simple. Apps Script: https://www.google.com/script/start/
API tutorial: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api I know this isn't the answer your looking for but it's something.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

1. Use some kind of bridging technology. The *briefest* search turned up [this one](http://www.php-javascript.com/), for instance. Edit: User [blues](https://stackoverflow.com/users/803194/blues) mentions [PHP V8js](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php) as well.
2. Have a Node process running and bound only to localhost, and have your PHP code make queries to it (perhaps via HTTP).

Comment: If node was installed on the same server, I guess you wouldn't necessarily need a node http server running. You could just exec node files, right?

Comment: @Don'tPanic: Fair point, absolutely. You'd have the cost of spinning up a process, though, which is fairly costly, as opposed to connecting to an existing process. But yes, quite true. :-)