# Is there any library or is it possible to evaluate javascript inside php?

Tags: javascript, php

I have some html with inline javascript, I want to extract some values by php, shortly, I'm looking for something like:

```
<?php
$jsre = new JavascriptRunTime();
$jsre->run("var a = 1; var b = a + 1; var c = {hello: a, world: b};");

$a = $jsre->lookinto("a"); // $a = 1;
$b = $jsre->lookinto("b"); // $b = 2;
$c = $jsre->lookinto("c"); // $c = array("hello" => 1, "world => 2");
```

Or is it possible to write one?

Comment: Javascript runs on the client, PHP on the server. What you propose is not possible.

Comment: You can try running node (which will in turn execute your JavaScript code) using `exec()` from PHP. Like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8620731/921204

Comment: It is possible to write a javascript interpreter in PHP. I'm not aware of an existing one. Probably it is to much work to create one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the closest thing to what you want -- I wouldn't trust anything but this

http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php

Comment: This is exactly what I want!! I hate to wait 8 mins to accept this anwser!